# laravel 5.4 multi tag update error when I view my html code

Tags: html, laravel-5, tags, laravel-5.4, blogs

I have two models, One of PostModel and other of TagModel. I have a error in many to many relationship when I view my HTML code and I get this error message. How I solve this problem. Thanks in Advice.

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

(2/2) ErrorException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getRelatedIds() (View: E:\Project\htdocs\portfolio\resources\views\pages\backend\posts\edit.blade.php)

(1/2) BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getRelatedIds()

**PostMode.php**

```
public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\TagModel', 'post_tag', 'post_id', 'tag_id');
    }
```

**TagModel.php**

```
public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\PostModel', 'post_tag', 'post_id', 'tag_id');
    }
```

Here is my Controller
**PostController.php**

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $posts      = PostModel::find($id);
        $tags       = TagModel::all();

        $tags2 = array();
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            $tags2[$tag->id] = $tag->name;
        }

        return view('pages.backend.posts.edit')->withPosts($posts)->withTags($tags2);
    }
```

**Here is my HTML code: (edit.blade.php)**

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="tags">Select Tags&nbsp;<span id="mark">*</span></label>
            <select name="tags[]" value="{{ $posts->tags }}" class="form-control select2 select2-multi" multiple="multiple"></select>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**And Here is my Javascript code:**

```
{!! Html::script('assets/backend/js/select2.min.js') !!}


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.select2-multi').select2();
    $('.select2-multi').select2().val({!! json_encode($posts->tags()->getRelatedIds()) !!}).trigger('change');

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the laravel helper getRelatedIds() to allRelatedIds()